# Are ciphers with a strength of 112 bits considered weak?

Tags: tls, brute-force, ciphers

SSL/TLS Ciphers of strength 128 bit is considered strong while ciphers of strength 112 bits is considered weak.

Ciphers of 56 bit is understandably weak as they can be easily brute-forced.

If it is weak, on what grounds is it considered weak and the reasonable time to brute-force it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are mixing brute-force attacks where bit size is relevant and other attacks. The 112 bit you refer to are probably from 3DES. This algorithm is not considered weak because of only 112 bit strength but because birthday attacks are possible: see the [Sweet32 attack](https://sweet32.info/).

Comment: Not forgetting the reason it's 112 for triple (56-bit) DES and not 168 is because of a [meet-in-the-middle attack](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/6345/why-is-triple-des-using-three-different-keys-vulnerable-to-a-meet-in-the-middle) (reinforcing the distinction between  *key size* and *effective strength*). Today a "perfect" 112-bit cipher is effectively unbreakable, requiring anything stronger allows for a good safety margin.